# Linear Independence with vectors and cross product.

Tags: vectors

(1) If a, b, c are three linearly independent vectors show that the vectors a × b, b × c,
c × a are also linearly independent.

(2) For any vector x, we express it in terms of these latter vectors
x = λa × b + µb × c + νc × a,

λ, µ, ν ∈ R. Find λ, µ and ν in terms of a, b, c and x.

No idea how to approach this. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=a \times b$ and so on. By definition, $u$ is orthogonal to both $a$ and $b$. Now consider,
\begin{align*}
c_1u+ c_2v +c_3w & = \mathbf{0}\\
(c_1u+ c_2v +c_3w) \cdot a & = \mathbf{0} \cdot a\\
c_2(a \cdot (b \times c)) & = 0.
\end{align*}
But $a,b,c$ are linearly independent, therefore $a \cdot (b \times c) \neq 0$, otherwise they will coplanar. This means $c_2=0$. Likewise we can get that all coefficients are $0$, thus linear independence.

Now use the same idea of taking dot product with appropriate vectors to solve for part (2).

Comment: i dont quite understand th 3rd line of working c2(a⋅(b×c))=0